# You can mark the path "..." as external to exclude it from the bundle - how?

Tags: javascript, import, package

I have a repository that I published to a package. I installed this package in another repository and want to use it but I get an error: (where the `...` are the name of any package that trying to import in my package)

```
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "@.../..."

    ../../node_modules/.../.../src/.../....ts:6:7:
      6 │ import "@.../...";
        ╵        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "@.../..." as external to exclude it from the bundle,
  which will remove this error.

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "@.../..."

    ../../node_modules/.../.../src/.../....ts:7:7:
      7 │ import "@.../...";
        ╵        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I refactor the url so I can use that package?

Comment: `npm i -S <the-package> --legacy-peer-deps` may also help in certain cases.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using `esbuild` for packaging, you should be able to use the `--external` flag:

```
esbuild entry.ts [...options...] '--external:<your dependency>'
```

cf. https://esbuild.github.io/api/#external